# Unable to generate token using Laravel Passport

Tags: authentication, oauth, token, laravel-passport, laravel-8

Trying to generate tokens via Laravel 8 Passport
by sending an Http Request to the endpoint, (using laravel valet to deploy apps)

`https://project.test/oauth/token`

my composer :

```
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^1.6",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.1",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.0"
```

I get this exception: It was not possible to parse your key, without specifying the reason why,
I tried to google it i found nothing, stick with this for days.

```
{
{
    "message": "It was not possible to parse your key, reason: ",
    "exception": "Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\InvalidKeyProvided",
    "file": "/Users/yassine/Desktop/apps/project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/InvalidKeyProvided.php",
    "line": 17,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/Users/yassine/Desktop/apps/project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php",
            "line": 85,
            "function": "cannotBeParsed",
            "class": "Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\InvalidKeyProvided",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/yassine/Desktop/apps/project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php",
            "line": 42,
            "function": "validateKey",
            "class": "Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\OpenSSL",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/yassine/Desktop/apps/project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php",
            "line": 18,
            "function": "getPrivateKey",
            "class": "Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\OpenSSL",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/yassine/Desktop/apps/project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/BaseSigner.php",
            "line": 38,
            "function": "createHash",
            "class": "Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\OpenSSL",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/yassine/Desktop/apps/project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Builder.php",
            "line": 568,
            "function": "sign",
            "class": "Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\BaseSigner",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/yassine/Desktop/apps/project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Builder.php",
            "line": 529,
            "function": "createSignature",
            "class": "Lcobucci\\JWT\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem, it is a change from PHP 8.0 in the return of OpenSSL.
Look:

https://php.watch/versions/8.0/OpenSSL-resource

[Change Open SSL PHP 8.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PucRs.png)

This validation was used in the lcobucci / jwt package.
They've already done an update that fixes the problem.

https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/commit/be0f2f94c4bd24a2c69a6af9e5949848c29a0921#diff-6019fde4d9e0d7d2d060b7fd9d8ebd89f85be6d89f61de292660c9a01bea8ca9R84

run composer update solved the problem for me

Comment: The problem is specifically the `lcobucci/jwt` sub-dependency of Passport, and v4 is the major version that is needed to get PHP 8 support. It can be updated by running `composer update lcobucci/jwt`, as long as you have Passport v10.1 or newer.